# Run a for loop concurrently and not sequentially in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark, concurrency

Below there is a **for loop** execution I am running on a Databricks cluster:

```py
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled = pd.DataFrame( 
                           {'IMEI' : ['001', '001', '001', '001', '001', '002', '002'],
                            'OuterSensorConnected':[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                            'OuterHumidity':[31.784826, 32.784826, 33.784826, 43.784826, 23.784826, 54.784826, 31.784826],
                            'EnergyConsumption': [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70],
                            'DaysDeploymentDate': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                            'label': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ]}
                           )
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled = spark.createDataFrame(datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled )

# printSchema of the datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled (spark df):

"root
 |-- IMEI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OuterSensorConnected: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- OuterHumidity: float (nullable = true)
 |-- EnergyConsumption: float (nullable = true)
 |-- DaysDeploymentDate: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = false)"

device_ids=datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled.select(sql_function.collect_set('IMEI').alias('unique_IMEIS')).collect()[0]['unique_IMEIS']

print(device_ids) #["001", "002", ..."030"] 30 ids

for i in device_ids:

  #filtered_dataset=datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled.where(datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled.IMEI.isin([i])) 
  #The above operation is executed inside the function training_models_operation_testing()

  try:
      training_models_operation_testing(i, datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled, drop_columns_not_used_in_training, training_split_ratio_value, testing_split_ratio_value, mlflow_folder, cross_validation_rounds_value, features_column_name, optimization_metric_value, pretrained_models_T_minus_one, folder_name_T_minus_one, timestamp_snap, instrumentation_key_value, canditate_asset_ids, executor, device_ids)

  except Exception as e:
      custom_logging_function("ERROR", instrumentation_key_value, "ERROR EXCEPTION: {0}".format(e))
```

*For the sake of the problem I have attached a sample data to have a general idea of how my data is..And imagine that many more rows and IDs exist. I have just created a few only for demonstration*

As you can see this is a simple function call inside a for loop in a Databricks cluster running with pyspark.

Briefly, I first create a list of the unique ids (IMEI column) existing in my dataset. This is equal to 30. Thus, I am running 30 iterations with the for loop. In each iteration I am executing the following steps:

- Filter the rows of the datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled (spark df) matching to each of the 30 asset ids. So let's say for example that out of the 40,000 rows of the initial df only 140 correspond to the first device id.
- Based on those 140 rows (filtered_dataset) the function does *preprocessing*, *train-test-split* and trains two *Spark ML* algorithms only for the rows of the filtered dataset.

The code snippet attached is working successfully. Although the *for loop* is executed sequentially, one iteration at a time. The function is called for the first id and only after completes it goes to the next id. However, what I want is to transform the above for loop in a way that the 30 iterations will run concurrently in **pyspark** and NOT **one-by-one**. How could I achieve this in pyspark?

I am open to discussion and ideas testing, because I understand that what I am asking may not be so simple to be executed in a Spark environment.

**My current output in logging** (this is something I print the way below)

Iteration 1 
Starting execution...  
- Executing the function for id 001  
Finished execution...

Iteration 2  
Starting execution...  
- Executing the function for id 002 
Finished execution...

**My desired output in logging** (this is something I print the way below)

Starting execution...  
- Executing the function for id 001  
- Executing the function for id 002  
- Executing the function for id 003  
- Executing the function for id 004  

.
.
.
.  
- Executing the function for id 030  
Finished execution...

All at the same time (concurrently) once

[Update] Based on the answer on the comments (threading module):

[image]

Comment: This is possible, you need to implement multi threading

Comment: @RohitNimmala Can you please provide an online guide or a spark implementation of it with multi-threading? ...I guess you mean something like this example https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: Provided an example in answers section as it wouldn't fit in comments section, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"for loop" is linear execution/ Sequential execution and can be considered as single threaded execution.

If you want to run your code concurrently, you need to create multiple threads/processes to execute your code.

Below is the example to achieve multi threading. I didn't test the code, but should work :)

```
#importing threading library

import threading

# Creating a list of threads
thread_list = []

#looping all objects, creating a thread for each element in the loop, and append them to thread_list
for items in device_ids:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=training_models_operation_testing,args=(items, datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled, drop_columns_not_used_in_training,
                                                   training_split_ratio_value, testing_split_ratio_value, mlflow_folder,
                                                   cross_validation_rounds_value, features_column_name,
                                                   optimization_metric_value, pretrained_models_T_minus_one,
                                                   folder_name_T_minus_one, timestamp_snap, instrumentation_key_value,
                                                   canditate_asset_ids, executor, device_ids,))
    thread_list.append(thread)

#Start multi threaded exucution
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.start()

#Wait for all threads to finish
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print("Finished executing all threads")
```

Comment: Appreciate your response and I will try your approach as soon as my Databricks cluster is back online. One additional concern of mine: If the function I am calling, training_models_operation_testing () does not return something, because it's only executes other sub-functions, will that be a problem when calling the ```threading.Thread()?```

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, it is very much similar to for loop except for concurrency.

Comment: This won't help as the threading is python is not based on pure concurrency as it implements GIL.. You should stick to concurrent futures or multiprocessing for this task as thread are sequential BTS.

Comment: @ShubhamJain Ok I will test both ways. As soon as my Databricks cluster is started. So, based on your opinion I should look something like that https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html....It would help me if you could post an example also using either concurrent.futures or multiprocessing based on my question. In any case I will get my hands dirty if I spot something non-manageable I will come back with the results.

Comment: @ShubhamJain Please check the screenshot update on my question. The threading module worked perfectly...I have tested an opposite execution with the concurrent.futures but I couldn't managed to achieve parallelism like the approach of Rohit...So unless you provide a valid answer where Concurrent.Futures outperforms Threading answer of Rohit, for me Rohit gave a valid answer.

Comment: @RohitNimmala I have a question for your regarding your answer. It's a more Databricks related question....I have run my example for 28 iterations and it runs pretty fast with 32 CPU cores (~5 minutes). Although increasing the concurrent iteration to 77 (~x3 more iterations) my execution takes about 1,5-2hours with 32 CPU cores. Is there any way to split the concurrent iterations into two parts or somehow optimize this threading execution?

Comment: @NikSp you can divide into batches (queues), and run them in batches, refer to below link: https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/

Comment: @RohitNimmala How can I print the outputs  of my print function in order? Because threading prints the print in random order...ie id 1 then id 4, then id 5, then id 3

Comment: @RohitNimmala I guess the link you provided cover also this...

Comment: @RohitNimmala I am quite struggling understanding how to implement this with the function you posted. Could you please edit your answer with the queue module? Thank you in advance for the help and advice.

Comment: @RohitNimmala please check those two questions I posted: 
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312240/split-multiple-threading-execution-to-batches-in-python, 

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310778/print-the-correct-order-of-multiple-print-statements-per-thread-in-pythons-thre